# How to use whereRaw with a column in (select .... )

Tags: laravel, select, eloquent, subquery

I made this Eloquent query:

```
Customers::WhereRaw('CUSTID in (Select distinct CUSTID from [CRMDB].[dbo].[EQUIPMENTS]')
        ->select('CUSTID', 'SHORTNAME')
        ->orderBy('SHORTNAME');
```

My intent was:
1) To get only these two columns (CUSTID and SHORT NAME), because Customers has almost 200 fields;
2) The Customers table has thousands of recs, I only need the customers that is in table EQUIPMENT

When a run this, commes up a looping. I have to stop IIS to break it.

Does anybody can help?
1) What is wrong?
2) What is the best way to do it instead of mine?

Comment: Are you familiar with Eloquent relationships?

Comment: Not so much, I'm newbie in laravel. sorry.

Comment: Can you replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` and post the result?

Comment: Reorganize your logic creating models and relationships is an viable alternative to your project?

Comment: In your suggestion you gave-me the answer. The ->get() was missing. Now it works. Thanks.